# Can't fully understand Token Based Authentication Logins

Tags: authentication, jwt, token

I've looked at many different websites and articles and I have an okay understanding of it. The question that I have is, Where do we store this token once the user signs in so we can have it handy for ajax calls and other api calls?
What other info should we capture when creating the token to be saved into the database to ensure the security? the server that created it and the time? would that be good enough?
Thank you for your help in advance!

Answer (score 1):

**

> As I am an Expert in Django(Python), I can guide you only about Django Auth
> Token.

> This Answer is for Django Auth Tokens DRF

**

Your Question# **Where do we store this token once the user signs in so we can have it**

By-default Django Rest Framework Handle All Permissions and Authentication as DRF is an Advance face of Django.

When You add this line in your Project/settings.py File

```
INSTALLED_APP = [
   ...
   'rest_framework.authtoken'
]
```

and Apply the following command

```
python manage.py makemigrations

python manage.py migrate
```

Django rest framework by-default create a Table named as Token and migrate changes to your db.

To see the changes go to your project Django Admin Panel

```
127.0.0.1:8000/admin/
```

> More Over you can Add Permissions and Authentications in your project/settings.py for that particular user